# Combining RavenUserStore with RavenDB issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Has anyone been using RavenUserStore for account management within MVC application?

My web application was integrating fine with RavenUserStore when I was using an older version of RavenDB.client (version 2.XXXX). But once I upgraded the RavenDB.client package to version 3.0.3599, i receive the following error when trying to login.

```
Method not found:'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<!!0>> Raven.Client.LinqExtensions.ToListAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>)'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<!!0>> Raven.Client.LinqExtensions.ToListAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>)'.

Source Error: 
Line 51:             if (ModelState.IsValid)
Line 52:             {                
Line 53:                 var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
Line 54:                 if (user != null)
Line 55:                 {

Stack Trace: 
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<!!0>> Raven.Client.LinqExtensions.ToListAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>)'.]
   AspNet.Identity.RavenDB.Stores.<GetUserByUserName>d__2.MoveNext() +0
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine) +98
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine) +61
   AspNet.Identity.RavenDB.Stores.RavenIdentityStore`1.GetUserByUserName(String userName) +286
   AspNet.Identity.RavenDB.Stores.RavenUserStore`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +165
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +231
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
```

Does anyone have any idea what I have done wrong? Have i missed anything?

Any information on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andrew, we've the same situation here. After updated RavenDb Client to version `3.0.3660` we cannot login anymore: `[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1<!!0> Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession.LoadAsync(System.String)'.]`

Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: And do you use this packages perhaps: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNet.Identity.RavenDB ?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I stil havent resolved it yet. Sergi seems to have found a solution for this problem. I will give that a try soon.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally managed to find and solve the problem.

The issue is that the [AspNet.Identity.RavenDB](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AspNet.Identity.RavenDB) package is compiled against a different `Raven.Client` version, so what you can do is get the sources for that package from GitHub (link provided above), update the RavenDB package(s) through NuGet and recompile.

That'll give you a nice and shiny `AspNet.Identity.RavenDB.dll` compiled against your same version of `Raven.Client`. Just add this reference to your project and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Sergi. I shall give that a try to find out.